# Bypassing matrix multiplications on GLSL

Tags: glsl, vulkan

Imagine we have the following fragment shader written in GLSL, which will be compiled for Vulkan:

```
//Vertex I/O
layout(location = 0) in vec2 ex_texCoord;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_color;

//Uniform buffers
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D sampler;
layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform UniformBlock{
    mat4 ycbcr2rgbMtx;
};

void main() {
    vec4 sample = texture(sampler, ex_texCoord);
    out_color = ycbcr2rgbMtx*sample;
}
```

As seen, a matrix multiplication is performed for each fragment. However, sometimes that matrix might be identity, so the operation becomes transparent. My question is if it is worth the effort of writing an uniform value that allows bypassing the matrix multiplication. At first glance it may seem a obvious optimization, but I am not sure, as GPUs are quite fast at matrix operations and jumps usually have a performance cost. Here is the code above adapted:

```
//Vertex I/O
layout(location = 0) in vec2 ex_texCoord;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_color;

//Uniform buffers
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D sampler;
layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform UniformBlock{
    mat4 ycbcr2rgbMtx;
    int isRgb;
};

void main() {
    vec4 sample = texture(sampler, ex_texCoord);
    
    if(!isRgb) {
            sample = ycbcr2rgbMtx*sample;
    }

    out_color = sample;
}
```

PD: I am asking in general terms, regardless of a particular GPU make or architecture.

Edit: As far as I've read, the former one takes 4 GPU cycles. Does the later one take just one GPU cycle (in the case of the happy path of isRgb=true)?

Comment: There seem to be some sentence snipped in your Q after "otherwise". This sounds like a  case for push constants. Or having two shaders. Which means there won't even be an `if` executed. Of course for your minimal sample it would probably not matter as it would be drown by memory access. You always have to measure when it comes to premature optimization ideas.

Comment: I cant use push constants, as in the real code there would be bore than 2 matrices, which surpass the 128B limit for push constants

Comment: Ups, I meant specialization constants.